# How to implement Custom table with dynamic rowspan in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-table, vuejs2, vuetify.js

### Hello StackOverflow community!!!

It's my first stack overflow question. So forgive me if I made any mistakes in asking question.
I am thinking I will learned it, eventually.

**Problem Statement :**

I need to generate html table template code, for the following tables of varying structures depending on Data provided to table. Some of the Use cases :

- [Use Case 1 Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZf1e.png)
- [Use Case 2 Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U4G1.png)

The data array which I am getting from back-end API-

[is something like this (Input Data array)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCClj.png)

Where each row represent single JSON object of that passed Input list to table.

Which I want to show in following table format by writing common reusable code which should work for different input array too which will generate table as per that data.

[The resultant table structure for above data array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wlynk.png)

So that's it my overall problem statement. Hope you understood the problem statement.

**Question :**

So Is there any library like vue-good-table, priveVue in VueJs/Javascrpt community to implement solution for above problem statement which is more robust , reusable & resilient.
(Note : No Jquery please)

**My implementation :**

Currently the Code that I have Implemented is more custom based without using any library, but I worried it will get messy & difficult to handle in future & will not withstand complex table structure.

So any help on this is really appreciated. Web Developer community please Help your brother.
Thank you.

**Playground Code:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#customTbl",
  methods: {
    setRowVisibility: function(i, field) {
      var self = this;
      switch (field) {
        case 'dataRow1':
          {
            var flag1 = !i ? true : self.rows[i - 1].cell1.dataRow1 == self.rows[i].cell1.dataRow1 ? false : true;
            console.log('dataRow1', flag1);
            return flag1;
          }

        case 'dataRow2':
          {
            var flag1 = (i && self.rows[i].cell1.rowSpan != 0 && self.rows[i - 1].cell1.dataRow1 != self.rows[i].cell1.dataRow1);
            if (flag1) {
              console.log('dataRow2', flag1);
              return true;
            }
            var flag2 = !i ? true : self.rows[i - 1].cell2.dataRow2 == self.rows[i].cell2.dataRow2 ? false : true;
            console.log('dataRow2', flag2);
            return flag2;
          }
        case 'dataRow3':
          {
            var flag1 = (i && self.rows[i].cell1.rowSpan != 0 && self.rows[i - 1].cell1.dataRow1 != self.rows[i].cell1.dataRow1);
            if (flag1) {
              console.log('dataRow3', flag1);
              return true;
            }
            var flag2 = !i ? true : self.rows[i - 1].cell3.dataRow3 == self.rows[i].cell3.dataRow3 ? false : true;
            console.log('dataRow3', flag2);
            return flag2;
          }
        case 'dataRow4':
          {
            var flag1 = (i && self.rows[i].cell1.rowSpan != 0 && self.rows[i - 1].cell1.dataRow1 != self.rows[i].cell1.dataRow1);
            if (flag1) {
              console.log('dataRow4', flag1);
              return true;
            }
            var flag2 = !i ? true : self.rows[i - 1].cell4.dataRow4 == self.rows[i].cell4.dataRow4 ? false : true;
            console.log('dataRow4', flag2);
            return flag2
          }
        case 'dataRow5':
          {
            var flag1 = (i && self.rows[i].cell1.rowSpan != 0 && self.rows[i - 1].cell1.dataRow1 != self.rows[i].cell1.dataRow1);
            if (flag1) {
              console.log('dataRow5', flag1);
              return true;
            }
            var flag2 = !i ? true : self.rows[i - 1].cell5.dataRow5 == self.rows[i].cell5.dataRow5 ? false : true;
            console.log('dataRow5', flag2);
            return flag2
          }
        case 'dataRow6':
          {
            var flag1 = (i && self.rows[i].cell1.rowSpan != 0 && self.rows[i - 1].cell1.dataRow1 != self.rows[i].cell1.dataRow1);
            if (flag1) {
              console.log('dataRow6', flag1);
              return true;
            }
            var flag2 = !i ? true : self.rows[i - 1].cell6.dataRow6 == self.rows[i].cell6.dataRow6 ? false : true;
            console.log('dataRow6', flag2);
            return flag2
          }
        case 'dataRow7':
          {
            var flag1 = (i && self.rows[i].cell1.rowSpan != 0 && self.rows[i - 1].cell1.dataRow1 != self.rows[i].cell1.dataRow1);
            if (flag1) {
              console.log('dataRow7', flag1);
              return true;
            }
            var flag2 = !i ? true : self.rows[i - 1].cell7.dataRow7 == self.rows[i].cell7.dataRow7 ? false : true;
            if (!flag2) {
              var flag2 = !i ? true : self.rows[i - 1].cell6.dataRow6 == self.rows[i].cell6.dataRow6 ? false : true;
            }
            console.log('dataRow7', flag2);
            return flag2
          }
        case 'dataRow8':
          {
            var flag1 = (i && self.rows[i].cell1.rowSpan != 0 && self.rows[i - 1].cell1.dataRow1 != self.rows[i].cell1.dataRow1);
            if (flag1) {
              console.log('dataRow8', flag2);
              return true;
            }
            var flag2 = !i ? true : self.rows[i - 1].cell8.dataRow8 == self.rows[i].cell8.dataRow8 ? false : true;
            if (!flag2) {
              var flag2 = !i ? true : self.rows[i - 1].cell6.dataRow6 == self.rows[i].cell6.dataRow6 ? false : true;
            }
            console.log('dataRow8', flag2);
            return flag2
          }
        case 'dataRow9':
          {
            var flag1 = (i && self.rows[i].cell1.rowSpan != 0 && self.rows[i - 1].cell1.dataRow1 != self.rows[i].cell1.dataRow1);
            if (flag1) {
              console.log('dataRow9', flag1);
              return true;
            }
            var flag2 = !i ? true : self.rows[i - 1].cell9.dataRow9 == self.rows[i].cell9.dataRow9 ? false : true;
            console.log('dataRow9', flag2);
            return flag2;
          }
        case 'dataRow10':
          {
            var flag1 = (i && self.rows[i].cell1.rowSpan != 0 && self.rows[i - 1].cell1.dataRow1 != self.rows[i].cell1.dataRow1);
            if (flag1) {
              console.log('dataRow10', flag1);
              return true;
            }
            var flag2 = !i ? true : self.rows[i - 1].cell10.dataRow10 == self.rows[i].cell10.dataRow10 ? false : true;
            console.log('dataRow10', flag2);
            return flag2
          }
        default:
          break;
      }
    },
  },
  data: {

    columns: [{
      label: 'Column 1',
      field: 'dataRow1',
      type: 'string',
    }, {
      label: 'Column 2',
      field: 'dataRow2',
      type: 'string',
    }, {
      label: 'Column 3',
      field: 'dataRow3'
    }, {
      label: 'Column 4',
      field: 'dataRow4'
    }, {
      label: 'Column 5',
      field: 'dataRow5',
      type: 'string',
    }, {
      label: 'Column 6',
      field: 'dataRow6',
      type: 'string',
    }, {
      label: 'Column 7',
      field: 'dataRow7'
    }, {
      label: 'Column 8',
      field: 'dataRow8',
      type: 'string',
    }, {
      label: 'Column 9',
      field: 'dataRow9',
      type: 'string',
    }, {
      label: 'Column 10',
      field: 'dataRow10',
      type: 'string',
    }],
    rows: [{
        id: 1,
        cell1: {
          dataRow1: "ABC",
          rowSpan: 12

        },
        cell2: {
          dataRow2: ">48 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell3: {
          dataRow3: ">60 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell4: {
          dataRow4: 1000,
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell5: {
          dataRow5: "10000",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell6: {
          dataRow6: "IED",
          rowSpan: 5
        },
        cell7: {
          dataRow7: 1,
          rowSpan: 3
        },
        cell8: {
          dataRow8: "SFH",
          rowSpan: 3
        },
        cell9: {
          dataRow9: "620-679",
          rowSpan: 0
        },
        cell10: {
          dataRow10: 75,
          rowSpan: 0
        }
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        cell1: {
          dataRow1: "ABC",
          rowSpan: 12

        },
        cell2: {
          dataRow2: ">48 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell3: {
          dataRow3: ">60 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell4: {
          dataRow4: 1000,
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell5: {
          dataRow5: "10000",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell6: {
          dataRow6: "IED",
          rowSpan: 5
        },
        cell7: {
          dataRow7: 1,
          rowSpan: 3
        },
        cell8: {
          dataRow8: "SFH",
          rowSpan: 3
        },
        cell9: {
          dataRow9: "680-719",
          rowSpan: 0
        },
        cell10: {
          dataRow10: 80,
          rowSpan: 0
        }
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        cell1: {
          dataRow1: "ABC",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell2: {
          dataRow2: ">48 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell3: {
          dataRow3: ">60 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell4: {
          dataRow4: 1000,
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell5: {
          dataRow5: "10000",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell6: {
          dataRow6: "IED",
          rowSpan: 5
        },
        cell7: {
          dataRow7: 1,
          rowSpan: 3
        },
        cell8: {
          dataRow8: "SFH",
          rowSpan: 3
        },
        cell9: {
          dataRow9: "720+",
          rowSpan: 0
        },
        cell10: {
          dataRow10: 95,
          rowSpan: 0
        }
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        cell1: {
          dataRow1: "ABC",
          rowSpan: 12

        },
        cell2: {
          dataRow2: ">48 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell3: {
          dataRow3: ">60 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell4: {
          dataRow4: 1000,
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell5: {
          dataRow5: "10000",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell6: {
          dataRow6: "IED",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell7: {
          dataRow7: 2,
          rowSpan: 0
        },
        cell8: {
          dataRow8: "MTF",
          rowSpan: 0
        },
        cell9: {
          dataRow9: "640+",
          rowSpan: 0
        },
        cell10: {
          dataRow10: 80,
          rowSpan: 0
        }
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        cell1: {
          dataRow1: "ABC",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell2: {
          dataRow2: ">48 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell3: {
          dataRow3: ">60 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell4: {
          dataRow4: 1000,
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell5: {
          dataRow5: "10000",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell6: {
          dataRow6: "IED",
          rowSpan: 5
        },
        cell7: {
          dataRow7: "3 - 4",
          rowSpan: 0
        },
        cell8: {
          dataRow8: "MTF",
          rowSpan: 0
        },
        cell9: {
          dataRow9: "640+",
          rowSpan: 0
        },
        cell10: {
          dataRow10: 75,
          rowSpan: 0

        }
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        cell1: {
          dataRow1: "ABC",
          rowSpan: 12

        },
        cell2: {
          dataRow2: ">48 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell3: {
          dataRow3: ">60 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell4: {
          dataRow4: 1000,
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell5: {
          dataRow5: "10000",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell6: {
          dataRow6: "SHOM",
          rowSpan: 3
        },
        cell7: {
          dataRow7: 1,
          rowSpan: 3
        },
        cell8: {
          dataRow8: "SFH",
          rowSpan: 3
        },
        cell9: {
          dataRow9: "620-679",
          rowSpan: 0
        },
        cell10: {
          dataRow10: 75,
          rowSpan: 0

        }
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        cell1: {
          dataRow1: "ABC",
          rowSpan: 12

        },
        cell2: {
          dataRow2: ">48 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell3: {
          dataRow3: ">60 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell4: {
          dataRow4: 1000,
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell5: {
          dataRow5: "10000",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell6: {
          dataRow6: "SHOM",
          rowSpan: 3
        },
        cell7: {
          dataRow7: 1,
          rowSpan: 3
        },
        cell8: {
          dataRow8: "SFH",
          rowSpan: 3
        },
        cell9: {
          dataRow9: "680-719",
          rowSpan: 0
        },
        cell10: {
          dataRow10: 80,
          rowSpan: 0

        }
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        cell1: {
          dataRow1: "ABC",
          rowSpan: 12

        },
        cell2: {
          dataRow2: ">48 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell3: {
          dataRow3: ">60 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell4: {
          dataRow4: 1000,
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell5: {
          dataRow5: "10000",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell6: {
          dataRow6: "SHOM",
          rowSpan: 3
        },
        cell7: {
          dataRow7: 1,
          rowSpan: 3
        },
        cell8: {
          dataRow8: "SFH",
          rowSpan: 3
        },
        cell9: {
          dataRow9: "720+",
          rowSpan: 0
        },
        cell10: {
          dataRow10: 95,
          rowSpan: 0

        }
      },

      {
        id: 9,
        cell1: {
          dataRow1: "ABC",
          rowSpan: 12

        },
        cell2: {
          dataRow2: ">48 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell3: {
          dataRow3: ">60 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell4: {
          dataRow4: 1000,
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell5: {
          dataRow5: "10000",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell6: {
          dataRow6: "INV",
          rowSpan: 4
        },
        cell7: {
          dataRow7: 1,
          rowSpan: 2
        },
        cell8: {
          dataRow8: "SFH",
          rowSpan: 2
        },
        cell9: {
          dataRow9: "620-679",
          rowSpan: 0
        },
        cell10: {
          dataRow10: 75,
          rowSpan: 0

        }
      },
      {
        id: 10,
        cell1: {
          dataRow1: "ABC",
          rowSpan: 12

        },
        cell2: {
          dataRow2: ">48 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell3: {
          dataRow3: ">60 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell4: {
          dataRow4: 1000,
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell5: {
          dataRow5: "10000",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell6: {
          dataRow6: "INV",
          rowSpan: 4
        },
        cell7: {
          dataRow7: 1,
          rowSpan: 2
        },
        cell8: {
          dataRow8: "SFH",
          rowSpan: 2
        },
        cell9: {
          dataRow9: "680",
          rowSpan: 0
        },
        cell10: {
          dataRow10: 85,
          rowSpan: 0

        }
      },
      {
        id: 11,
        cell1: {
          dataRow1: "ABC",
          rowSpan: 12

        },
        cell2: {
          dataRow2: ">48 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell3: {
          dataRow3: ">60 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell4: {
          dataRow4: 1000,
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell5: {
          dataRow5: "10000",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell6: {
          dataRow6: "INV",
          rowSpan: 4
        },
        cell7: {
          dataRow7: 2,
          rowSpan: 0
        },
        cell8: {
          dataRow8: "MTF",
          rowSpan: 0
        },
        cell9: {
          dataRow9: "660+",
          rowSpan: 0
        },
        cell10: {
          dataRow10: 75,
          rowSpan: 0

        }
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        cell1: {
          dataRow1: "ABC",
          rowSpan: 12

        },
        cell2: {
          dataRow2: ">48 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell3: {
          dataRow3: ">60 months",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell4: {
          dataRow4: 1000,
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell5: {
          dataRow5: "10000",
          rowSpan: 12
        },
        cell6: {
          dataRow6: "INV",
          rowSpan: 4
        },
        cell7: {
          dataRow7: "3 - 4",
          rowSpan: 0
        },
        cell8: {
          dataRow8: "MTF",
          rowSpan: 0
        },
        cell9: {
          dataRow9: "660+",
          rowSpan: 0
        },
        cell10: {
          dataRow10: 75,
          rowSpan: 0

        }
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```css
.HelpPlateBody {
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

.PlateBody {
  background: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #cacaca;
  border-left: 1px solid #cacaca;
  padding: 0 0px;
}

lement.style {
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
}

.GraphSort {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.GraphSortHead {
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

element.style {
  padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
}

.GraphSortBody {
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  padding: 0 5px 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.EffectiveDate {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

strong,
b {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.Clear {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.HelpPageContent table {
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.DataTableCamp {
  border-left: 1px solid #cacaca;
  border-right: 1px solid #cacaca;
}

.DataTable {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.DataTableCamp th {
  background: #eaeaea;
  border-right: none;
}

.DataTable th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  border-top: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-right: 1px solid #dadada;
  padding: 8px 10px;
}

.DataTableCamp {
  border-left: 1px solid #cacaca;
  border-right: 1px solid #cacaca;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

.DataTable {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.HelpPageContent table td {
  border-right: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-left: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.DataTableCamp td {
  border-right: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.DataTable td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-right: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.11/vue.js"></script>
<div id="customTbl">
  <div class="PlateBody HelpPlateBody">
    <br />
    <div class="GraphSort" style="margin:0 0 -1px">
      <div class="GraphSortHead">
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="GraphSortBody" style="padding:5px 0 5px 10px;">
        <b>
         Table Title
          <a id="fharlla"></a>
        </b>
        <div class="Clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <thead>
        <tr class="DataTable DataTableCamp">
          <th v-for="(column, i) in columns">
            <b>{{column.label}}</b>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <template v-for="(rowData, i) in rows">
          <tr class="DataTable DataTableCamp">
            <template v-if="rowData.cell1.rowSpan==0">
              <td>{{rowData.cell1.dataRow1}}</td>
            </template>
        <template v-else-if="setRowVisibility(i,'dataRow1')">
              <td :rowSpan="rowData.cell1.rowSpan">{{rowData.cell1.dataRow1}}</td>
            </template>
        <template v-if="rowData.cell2.rowSpan==0">
              <td>{{rowData.cell2.dataRow2}}</td>
            </template>
        <template v-else-if="setRowVisibility(i,'dataRow2')">
              <td :rowSpan="rowData.cell2.rowSpan">{{rowData.cell2.dataRow2}}</td>
            </template>
        <template v-if="rowData.cell3.rowSpan==0">
              <td>{{rowData.cell3.dataRow3}}</td>
            </template>
        <template v-else-if="setRowVisibility(i,'dataRow3')">
              <td :rowSpan="rowData.cell3.rowSpan">{{rowData.cell3.dataRow3}}</td>
            </template>
        <template v-if="rowData.cell4.rowSpan==0">
              <td>{{rowData.cell4.dataRow4}}</td>
            </template>
        <template v-else-if="setRowVisibility(i,'dataRow4')">
              <td :rowSpan="rowData.cell4.rowSpan">{{rowData.cell4.dataRow4}}</td>
            </template>
        <template v-if="rowData.cell5.rowSpan==0">
              <td>{{rowData.cell5.dataRow5}}</td>
            </template>
        <template v-else-if="setRowVisibility(i,'dataRow5')">
              <td :rowSpan="rowData.cell5.rowSpan">{{rowData.cell5.dataRow5}}</td>
            </template>
        <template v-if="rowData.cell6.rowSpan==0">
              <td>{{rowData.cell6.dataRow6}}</td>
            </template>
        <template v-else-if="setRowVisibility(i,'dataRow6')">
              <td :rowSpan="rowData.cell6.rowSpan">{{rowData.cell6.dataRow6}}</td>
            </template>
        <template v-if="rowData.cell7.rowSpan==0">
              <td>{{rowData.cell7.dataRow7}}</td>
            </template>
        <template v-else-if="setRowVisibility(i,'dataRow7')">
              <td :rowSpan="rowData.cell7.rowSpan">{{rowData.cell7.dataRow7}}</td>
            </template>
        <template v-if="rowData.cell8.rowSpan==0">
              <td>{{rowData.cell8.dataRow8}}</td>
            </template>
        <template v-else-if="setRowVisibility(i,'dataRow8')">
              <td
                :rowSpan="rowData.cell8.rowSpan"
              >{{rowData.cell8.dataRow8}}</td>
            </template>
        <template v-if="rowData.cell9.rowSpan==0">
              <td>{{rowData.cell9.dataRow9}}</td>
            </template>
        <template v-else-if="setRowVisibility(i,'dataRow9')">
              <td
                :rowSpan="rowData.cell9.rowSpan"
              >{{rowData.cell9.dataRow9}}</td>
            </template>
        <template v-if="rowData.cell10.rowSpan==0">
              <td>{{rowData.cell10.dataRow10}}</td>
            </template>
        <template v-else-if="setRowVisibility(i,'dataRow10')">
              <td :rowSpan="rowData.cell10.rowSpan">{{rowData.cell10.dataRow10}}</td>
            </template>
        </tr>
        </template>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
```

Comment: you can do that with vuetify `v-data-table` without probably any problems or difficulties, just instead of using `rowSpan` , you can use `v-slot:item.<columnName>` and put multiple `<tr>`s in a `v-for` loop and it basically looks the same.

Comment: @M3HDI Ok sure thanks buddy